# How do I unzip, install and run the game Xonotic.zip?

Tags: software-installation, internet, files, games, unzip

I have downloaded Xonotic using the orange download button on the site, but now I have no idea how to:

1. Unzip the zip file of Xonotic
2. Install Xonotic
3. Run the game Xonotic

I have looked everywhere, please help.

Comment: Start out with extracting the ZIP.

Comment: try reading `man tar`.

Comment: Right-click and select 'Extract Here.'

Comment: Regardless, it doesn't show much research or effort - "I have no idea how to unzip... I have looked everywhere..."

Comment: @Jebidieah Cornell I have successfully unzipped and run Xonotic and given a fairly comprehensive answer below, happy gaming :)

Comment: @eyoung100 tar is not usually used for zip files?

Comment: @andrew.46 my apologies... mistook for `tar.xz`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right click the (**xonotic-0.8.2.zip**) (**0.8.2** is the latest version at date) with your mouse and choose (**Extract here**)
2. Open the (**Xonotic**) folder
3. Start game by double click the purple (**xonotic-linux64-sdl**) icon.
   It might say windows instead of Linux and 32 instead of 64, depending on what OS you are using.

That's it! Can't get any easier.

O.B.S! **Xonotic require no installation!** it's all ready to go after the extract!

**Note A:** If you can't see the folder after the extracting has finnished you might need to restart your PC.

**Note B:** Since Xonotic require no installation you will have to download each map in each server 1 time. It will take a few MB of your HD storage.

[image: quidditch]

Comment: The answer was there already since July 29!

Comment: No one answered the questien the way i did.
When help, help as many possible at once and not only the one asking.
Not all people are computer geeks or like the terminal. So people can be a little bit more specific when answering to a questien otherwise the answer might become useless and not help anyone. Just like your comment. Have a nice day!

You can never help to much, but you can definitely help to little!

Comment: @Dr.Buntu Good to see a different method described! I have up-voted your answer...

Comment: Thank you andrew.46! appreciate it! doing it the way as i described above there is no need to open the Terminal and no need to jump between a txt document or this page to copy/paste any commands or any risk in typing in the wrong commands. Also Terminal is far known to be tricky when it comes to get the latest updates for any software/program. So in my opinion this is a more user friendly way of doing it and also saves time. Again, thanks for the up-vote. Wish you a great weekend!

Answer (score 13):

Downloading, unzipping and running Xonotic can be accomplished by opening a Terminal window and copying and pasting the following commands one at a time (Note: the file `xonotic-0.8.5.zip` is a reasonably big download at 1.1G) :

```
cd
wget http://dl.xonotic.org/xonotic-0.8.5.zip
unzip xonotic-0.8.5.zip
cd ~/Xonotic
./xonotic-linux-glx.sh
```

If the game does not run particularly well with the last command (it ran fine here) you can use this alternative:

```
cd ~/Xonotic
./xonotic-linux-sdl.sh
```

There are a few other choices in there including a Makefile that installs to `/usr/local` but the above will be enough to get the game running and I would advise simply running it *without* system installation.

The screenshot below shows me getting soundly pummeled playing the game:

[image]

**Note:** To get the screenshot above I utilised the quite handy 'windowed' mode which is run with the following command:

```
cd ~/Xonotic
./xonotic-linux-sdl.sh +vid_fullscreen 0
```

**References:**

- [Xonotic FAQs](http://www.xonotic.org/faq/)
- [Xonotic Forums](http://forums.xonotic.org/showthread.php?tid=15)

Comment: Screenshots can also be made simply by pressing the [ PRINT SCR ] button on your Keyboards upper middle part on the right side.

There is also a Shortcut bind for Screenshots ingame on F12. 

The game itself also makes automated screenshots of the Start/End of each game being automatically saved in the ( .xonotic ) folder. Which is a hidden folder by default in most OS. So you need to mark the show ( Hidden Files ) square to make it visible. In Window you find it in: C:\users\%username%\saved games\xonotic

.xonotic » data » screenshots :)