# Unable to run xonotic game in xubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, games

I recently installed xonotic game in mu xubuntu 18.04. I downloaded the game from software center.

When I try to open it it shows black screen which I have to end by manually restarting pc. When I try to open it using terminal I get some error as shown in the image that I have attached.

How can I run this this game on my pc?

[image: error shown by terminal when i run xonotic through terminal:]

[image: error continuation]

Comment: Interesting to see if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/q/790710/57576